# SaveOptions field not being honored..is my solution correct?

Tags: lotus-domino

Maybe I have figured it out.

I have a web form with a computed SaveOptions field...value is "0".  It is a hidden field.  I never want this form's document to save..it is only a mechanism that has some useful buttons/actions on it.

However, the document was being saved, when it shouldn't ever.

Now I have changed it so the field is NOT a hidden field, but instead I wrapped it in a 'div' tag with style set to "display:none;"

It seems like this is the solution for a web form, while in the Notes client I seem to remember that whether hidden or not, the field is honored.

Can someone confirm this sounds like what you would expect?

Answer (score 2):

There is a form option , which is called something like “generate html for all fields”. Enabling this option will generate html also for hidden fields. In that case the save options field will work even as a hidden field.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your feedback, I have been unable to look into this for a while.   I did what you suggested, and still have the SaveOptions field computed to "0" and not hidden, but wrapped in the div with display:none set....so I dont see the field (that's good)....but the document is still saving.    Worst case scenario I will have to have a scheduled agent clean these up afterwards, but this is very strange to me.

Comment: one more observation....maybe something was cached...now it does not appear to be saving.    Going to keep an eye on it, and will update this after a while.